# Get element from xml file

Tags: c#, xml

I have this problem:

I have a method

```
private  XmlElement ToXmlElement(string xml)
        {
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.LoadXml(xml);
            return doc.DocumentElement;
        }
```

And my input xml string is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Collection xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="urn:IEEE-1671:2009.02:Common">
<Item name="edsw">
<Collection />
</Item>
</Collection>
```

I need to return from this string XmlElement, which looks like:

```
<Collection xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="urn:IEEE-1671:2009.02:Common">
    <Item name="edsw">
    <Collection />
    </Item>
    </Collection>
```

thats everything without `<?xml version ="1.0"?>`
but doc.DocumentElements returns me only:

```
<Item name="edsw" xmlns="urn:IEEE-1671:2009.02:Common">
<Collection />
</Item>
```

is there any way how to achieve it?

Comment: That does not happen to me. `DocumentElement` returns the whole `Collection`. How are you converting the result to string?

Comment: when I am debuggin it i see in DocumentElement inner xml only this, not whole collection,

Comment: string ToStringElement(XmlElement xml) {StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(); XmlTextWriter writter = new XmlTextWritter(sw); xml.WriteTo(writter); return sw.toString(); }

Comment: After fixing your typos, `ToStringElement(ToXmlElement(xml))` returns the whole `Collection`. That means `ToXmlElement()` actually does what you want it to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the `OuterXml`, that's where you will find what you need:

```
doc.DocumentElement.OuterXml
```

Comment: but thats only string, I need to return XmlElement

Comment: @Martin Ch, well you already have it: `doc.DocumentElement`, that's what you are returning. When you are debugging look at the `OuterXml` property and not the `InnerXml`.